# Committing after checkout. Git says "You are not working on a branch."

Tags: git

I reverted to a previous commit and made some changes.

Now I want to commit my changes and GIT says "You are not working on a branch. This commit will be unreferenced when switching to another branch and can be lost."

I don't care about any commits I made after this one, how do I commit now?

[image: Git extensions screenshot.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you revert? What is the result of **git status**?

It looks like you've reset to a commit on a non-local branch. You can create a new branch for your commits using;

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

You may need to delete or force-push the old branch, but only do so if you are sure you do not need the commits on it. I find using **git log** or **gitk** can help to visualise this.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to illustrate the state of things.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you created a [detached head](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) by using `git checkout` to turn back the clock.  This means your current `HEAD` does not point to the head of a branch anymore.

If you're 100% sure you don't want anything after the commit, you can use `git stash` to save your current work, `git reset --hard <commit>` [(man page)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to revert back to the commit, then `git stash apply` to apply your new changes.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to illustrate the state of things.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a detached head.

Comment: What if I do want to keep the changes that I made before in the repository, even though I'm not going to use them right now?

Comment: Then you follow RJFalconer's advice and create a new branch instead of wiping out the work.

Comment: @Olhovsky: For reference: to switch the current branch to another point, use `git reset`, to switch only the working directory (and HEAD) to some point without affecting any branch, use `git checkout`.